# Flurry does not report all errors

Tags: android, service, flurry

I am using flurry o trace crash and errors in my Android app. I recently discovered a problem where some of my errors (recorded with the onError() method) does  not show on the flurry analitycs.

To test if it wasn't some sort of configuration problem or delay, I fired some errors with the same configuration from differents place of my app. As a result I saw that errors fired from activity are correctly received, but some errors fired from my services are not received. 
I enabled the flurry log, and they say that those errors are sent, but the flurry dashboard does not see them.

For example, an error that is never received is one I fire from a custom UncaughtExceptionHandler, since Flurry does not report service crash either. Here is its code :

```
    final Context context = this;
    final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR DETECTED------------------------------------------", ex);
            //Utils.sendFlurryError(context, "serviceCrash", "Uncaught error in Swiper Sevice",new Exception(ex));
            FlurryAgent.onError("serviceCrash","Uncaught error in Swiper Service",ex );
            NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 42, new Intent(context, AppConstants.LAUNCH_CLASS), 0))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif2)
                            //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.logo_rond))
                    .setGroup("swiper")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Swiper")
                    .setContentText("Swiper met an error. Please restart swiper to correct it");
            manager.notify(Notification.SWIPER_NOTIF_ID, builder.build());
           uncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }

    });
```

If any of you encountered this kind of bug and know a way around, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this for crash tracking

https://www.crashlytics.com/

This is a good library, made by twitter.

Comment: Does not really answer my problem, but it works so... meh.

Answer (score 0):

`onError` was built more as an analog to logging events than as an answer for crash reporting.  In fact, the trace you submit will be truncated after 256 characters, which is the max length a value can have in an event.

Flurry does, however, offer a crash reporting solution which should suffice in this instance.

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/overview/lexicon/crashanalytics/

Comment: I am using the crash analytic solution from Flurry but as I say in the problem description, service crash are not reported while activity crashes are.

Comment: I don't see a session being managed there, which might explain it.  However, you probably don't want to do this that way, as the side effect would likely be inflated session counts and long sessions.

To start and end a session, you'd need to call onStarSession and onEndSession.  We typically discourage sessions in this fashion, but it can be done.